# iraf, make: *** No rule to make target 'sptable'. Stop

Tags: linux, package, updates, iraf

I am working with Iraf and I need to install the external package "sptable". The only way I found in order to install Iraf nowadays is described in this site: 
https://glauffer.github.io/2018-08-03-the-easy-way-to-install-iraf/
In order to install sptable I found two site which describe the same procedure: https://iraf.net/article.php?story=20140924103515277  and
https://star.pst.qub.ac.uk/wiki/doku.php/public/teaching-linux-systems/other_software_-_astroconda_iraf

In both cases, when I try the command "make" (make self_update or make sptable) I get this message error:
"make: *** No rule to make target `sptable (or self_update) '. Stop"

How can I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends a bit on the system you are using. When you are on Debian or its derivatives (Ubuntu, Mint etc.), you can install IRAF and sptable just with `apt install iraf iraf-sptable`. On other systems, go to https://iraf-community.github.io and follow the installation instructions to install IRAF. For sptable, you should do a `mkpkg -p sptable` in the source directory of [sptable](https://github.com/iraf-community/iraf-sptable).